# Redirect_to :back stops working after refreshing page in Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using `redirect_to :back` to go to the previous page in ruby on rails project, but when i refresh the page it doesn't work any more, how can we retain the previous page url stored in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your last page in session.

```
session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
```

And instead `redirect_to :back`, put this:

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```